# Neo4j : can you set extra data on a resource when returning it?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `User` nodes, and then a bunch of relationships to other nodes.

As well as returning the `User`, I need some aggregated data about some of the relationships,  `following`, `followers` etc.

At the moment, I return the `User` and these extra properties separately, and then in my app I have to merge the extra properties into my user object.

```
match (user:User {id:1234})
optional match ()<-[f:Follows]-user
with user, count(f) as following
optional match ()-[f:Follows]->user'
with user, following, count(f) as followers
return user, followers, following
```

Which results in

```
user         | following | follows
----------------------------------
User {       | 10        | 30 
  id:1234,   |           |
  name:foo   |           |
}            |           |
```

And then I take the results, and mix in `following`, `follows` into the `User` object.

However, It would be far simpler, and less code if the cypher could do this for me, so it would return one 'User' object...

```
 user       
----------------------------------
User { 
  id:1234,
  name:foo,
  following:10,
  follows:30
}
```

However, I don't want these saved against the User resource, just calculated at lookup.

Any idea if this is possible?  I had a look at Collect, but I couldnt see a way to append extra data to an existing resource at return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher can return arbitrary property maps:

```
match (user:User {id:1234})
optional match ()<-[f:Follows]-user
with user, count(f) as following
optional match ()-[f:Follows]->user
with user, following, count(f) as followers
return { id: user.id, name: user.name, following: following, followers: followers }
```

I'm not sure if this is convenient if your user carries a lot of properties, however.

Comment: yeah, thats the issue, there are a few of them.

Comment: @MattBryson: there's always a workaround (even if it means resorting to reflection and string concatenation) but I'm wondering; why do you merge it into your domain object? It might be more convenient/make more sense to create additional DTO classes to hold the columns of your result set.

Comment: in 3.1. you can `return user { .* }`